# My RecyclerView CardView doesn't populate from firebase and the app crashes. I'm Using a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Here's my fragment

I don't know what seems to be wrong here. I tried everything that i could think of. Still crashing. Can anyone suggest a solution ?

```
public class Entreprisesfrag extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference dbref;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

public Entreprisesfrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entreprises, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    DatabaseReference dbref= firebaseDatabase.getReference("Entreprises");


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class,ViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class, ViewHolder>
            (entreprises_class.class,R.layout.entreprises_cardview, ViewHolder.class,dbref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, entreprises_class model, int position) {
            viewHolder.details(getContext(), model.getNom(), model.getSecteur(), model.getSous_secteur(), model.getImage());


        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}



@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.recherche_activity_menu_item, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Do search code here
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.recherche)
    {

    }
    else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.filtrer)
    {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Erreur de connexion ! Vérifiez l'adresse email utilisée et le mot de passe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

//ViewHolder

This is my ViewHolder Class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

View mview;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mview=itemView;
}

public void details(Context cntx, String nom, String secteur, String sous_secteur, String image){

    TextView textView= mview.findViewById(R.id.nom_entreprise);
    TextView textView1= mview.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_secteur);
    TextView textView2= mview.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_sous_secteur);

    textView.setText(nom);
    textView1.setText(secteur);
    textView2.setText(sous_secteur);

}

}
```

Over Here's my getter and setter other Class

```
public class entreprises_class {

String nom, secteur, sous_secteur, image;

public entreprises_class() {

}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getSecteur() {
    return secteur;
}

public void setSecteur(String secteur) {
    this.secteur = secteur;
}

public String getSous_secteur() {
    return sous_secteur;
}

public void setSous_secteur(String sous_secteur) {
    this.sous_secteur = sous_secteur;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting an instance of the Firebase Database in onCreate, before getting a reference to it.

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: appsbyjoel.go, PID: 3608
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreateView() change:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

to:

```
recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

It gives NullPointerException because you are referring to the global variable you defined.

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much